# how to make bash script that takes in one text files and outputs the data in an organised file?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I haven't done any major scripting before, but basically I'm trying to make a script that takes in a file called people.txt with data that looks like this:

```
Steve Wozniak:Engineer:USA:1950
```

And makes a new file with that data organised like this:

```
Name: Steve Wozniak
Occupation: Engineer
Country: USA
Date of Birth: 1950
```

I've given it a try using this:

```
cat people.txt | awk -v RS=":" '{print "Name: " $1}'
```

This gives me a list of every field with the title `name` How do I separate it?

I've got a couple more 'features' I plan on adding in, but I'm hoping I'll be able to figure those out. Would anybody be able to help me out and/or point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's supposed to fix the misspelling of `Engineer` while it reorganizes it? :)

Comment: @Barmar 'course. What do you think an Enigneer does?

Comment: @Barmar woops, nice catch. we can safely assume that the data file will be made by someone who is a much better speller than me

Comment: @Barmar you're right. I've given it a try but I'm stuck on seperating the fields, please check out my edit

Comment: `RS` is Record Separator. You need to set `FS`, the Field Separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FS` is the field separator, not `RS`. You can set it using the `-F` option to `awk`

```
awk -F: '{
        print "Name:", $1;
        print "Occupation:", $2; 
        print "Country:", $3; 
        print "Date of Birth:", $4
}' input.txt
```

Comment: Cool, I've written up a very similar solution. How do I output the newly organised data into a new file?

Comment: With normal bash output redirection `> output.txt`

Comment: I should have known that, sorry for all the dumb questions. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

at least this is one way:

```
kent$ paste <(echo "Name\nOcuupation\nCountry\nDate of Birth") <(awk -v RS=":" '$1=$1' <<<"Steve Wozniak:Engineer:USA:1950")  
Name    Steve Wozniak
Ocuupation      Engineer
Country USA
Date of Birth   1950
```

awk alone can do it too. for example, `-F: -v OFS=":" '{print "Name",$1;print "Occ..",$2; print ...}'`

Comment: Will your `paste` solution work for multiple records in the data file?

Comment: @Barmar no it won't, the paste one just works for the given example. If there are multiple records, use the 2nd option. same as your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=: read name job home dob

do
        echo -e "Name: $name \nOccupation: $job \nCountry: $home \nDate of Birth: $dob"
        echo " "
done < "$1"
```

Usage: `% scriptname.sh filename`